# How can I implement synchronous registration on a website and a forum by linking their databases?

Tags: database, web, authorization, xenforo

I am developing a website that will include many sections with articles and a separate section for a forum with individual topics. For organizing the forum, I have chosen the **XenFORO** framework, which requires a registration process. I need to ensure the synchronization of the user registration process for both the main site and the forum. Additionally, I want to create a unified administrative panel that would allow managing both the site and the forum from one place. I am facing difficulties in understanding how to effectively set up these interactions and integration.

It might be necessary to use OAuth2.

Comment: You have two vastly different questions here.  You should (1) split these out into two separate questions, but also (2) make sure to explain what you've tried, what research you've done, exactly *what* you don't understand about the research you've done, etc. *"facing difficulties in understanding how"* doesn't give the community much background. We don't want people to waste their time (and yours) giving answers that you've already come across. See [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask), specifically *"Search, and research ..."*.  Thanks!